# Read XML file with jQuery

Tags: jquery, xml, xml-parsing

I have an xml file in the form:

```
<cart>
<itemCount>1</itemCount>
<cartTotal>33.94</cartTotal>
</cart>
```

This is to track what is in the contents of an ecommerce shopping cart. So it will always only have one "cart" node.

I want to read the "cartTotal" field. If it is greater than 0, then I want to display my "View cart" button on the website.

I've tried the following and it isn't working:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "https://www.example.com/file.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('cart').each(function(){
                if (($(this).attr('cartTotal')) > 0) {
                    $("a.view-cart-button").css('visibility', 'visible');
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements within `<cart>...</cart>` are not **attributes** but **child nodes**.

Replace:

```
if (($(this).attr('cartTotal')) > 0) {
    $("a.view-cart-button").css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

With:

```
if ( $('cartTotal',$(this)).text()*1 > 0) {
    $("a.view-cart-button").css('visibility', 'visible');
}
```

**AMENDMENT**

With the caveat that calling XML files, using AJAX, on another domain and without [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) access in place, this will fail, try the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET" ,
        url: "https://secure.ultracart.com/cgi-bin/UCJavaScript?merchantid=DEMO&type=xml" ,
        dataType: "xml" ,
        success: function(xml) {
            if( $(xml).find('cartTotal').text()*1 > 0 ){
                $("a.view-cart-button").css('visibility', 'visible');
            }
        }
    });

});​
```

If you are dealing with a payment gateway, or similar, refer to their documentation first - they will specify how you can interact with them from your own site.

Comment: It's still not working. Maybe it has something to do with the evaluation against "0"?

Comment: Possibly. And/or try and multiply the text value (which will, of course, be a string) by 1. See amended code above.

Comment: Still not working. I tried putting an alert inside the success function and it never went off. So the code is never even getting in there?? Hmmm...my XML file looks like https://secure.ultracart.com/cgi-bin/UCJavaScript?merchantid=DEMO&type=xml

Comment: Made further changes. Be aware that, if you are calling a third-party to gather the XML via AJAX, you may not be able to do so due to security settings.

Comment: The code looks good. I'm guessing it's the security issue then. Thanks so much for your time!